# Getting query-string after two consecutive HttpGET

Tags: java, android, http-request

in my android application I execute an HTTP GET using this url:

http://www.atm-mi.it/it/Giromilano/Pagine/default.aspx?s_place_hd=milano&e_place_hd=milano&s_add_hd=via%20dante%201&e_add_hd=corso%20sempione%2014

but the request is redirect to this url:

http://www.atm-mi.it/it/Giromilano/Pagine/default.aspx?bwid=c3854196-39e9-48cb-81ead0b80116c748-4f6b2880&wbt=nav&contextname=c3854196-39e9-48cb-81ead0b80116c748-4f6b2880&vp=174&ORIGINE=milano&DESTINAZIONE=milano

(try this on your browser and you see the url changes)

my problem is: how can i retrieve the bwid value from within the first GET?

Consider that this value is generated dinamically after every new submit associate to the button "Calcola"

Answer (score 0):

In all likelyhood, you are being redirected. Depending on how you implemented your request, you may have to use different solutions. Here is one, if you used the `URL` class.

If you get a redirect (3XX Http status codes), look for the 'Location' header in the response and go to the value of that header.